# Average of the smallest 3 values results in Err539

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

Given a set of values, I want to get the average of the 3 smallest values in one formula.

To do this, I found a similiar recipe for the 3 biggest values on https://exceljet.net/formula/average-top-3-scores

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(range,{1,2,3}))
```

But I'am not able to get this work (doesn't matter if I use `SMALL` or `LARGE`).

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

By the way, this is LibreOffice Calc but I hope that it behaves like Excel.

If I enter this formula, Calc changes it to `=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A6;{1,20,3}))` (2 has changed to 20).

Even if I change the function type to *Array* it doesn't work:

[image: Array formula]

What I'am **not** want is to use auxiliary cells to calc the first, second and third smallest value and averging over this 3 cells.

Comment: try changing out the semicolon for a comma.

Comment: @jsteurer thank you. With a comma instead the semicolon `=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A6,{1,2,3}))` Calc interprets `A1:A6,{1,2,3}` only as one argument for `SMALL`.
As described [here](https://www.excel-exercise.com/comma-or-semicolon-in-excel-formula/) this could relate to the fact, that my OS is set to german. Changing the commas from `{1,2,3}` to semicolons `{1;2;3}` doesn't work too :(